# Is there a google app engine api?

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to implement some form of access control for a REST API implemented in App engine. Is it possible to get the list of GAE Applications that a user has permissions to administer or view in the app engine console. Or whether the user has permissions to administer/view the current application.

Note: the Users API does not work for me because this is a rest server called by another google app not a web service called by a user from the browser. OAuth API seems promising but I was unable to find an OAuth scope or rest endpoint for getting GAE related information.

Answer (score 2):

there is no API that can provide a "list of GAE Applications that a user has permissions to administer." Google Cloud Endpoints on App Engine (Trusted Tester program) may be useful for hosting custom RESTful APIs with user authorization  may be useful, read more here: http://endpoints-trusted-tester.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

There must be an API as the Google Eclipse plugin is using it.

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/signin?hl=de

But it is not documented.